# In VS Is there a way to change all derived classes method arguments at once?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, inheritance, refactoring

Basically the title. But I will provide an example in case I didn't word it correctly.

```
public abstract class A
{
    public abstract void Method(Foo foo);
}

public class B : A
{
    public override void Method(Foo foo)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class C : A
{
    public override void Method(Foo foo)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I want to change (Foo foo) in every class related to "class A" all at once. I could do a find and replace, but if I use that method name anywhere else it risks damaging other code.

I am planning on having maybe hundreds of classes derived from a abstract so I would like to know I can change things down the line.

Comment: You are asking about a `change signature` refactoring, not just search-replace. Even if Visual Studio 2017 doesn't have such a refactoring, Resharper probably does.

Comment: Tools like ReSharper can do this. I don't know if this is possible in vanilla Visual Studio.

Comment: If you have them all in your solution and no further client-code you could do it via ReSharper.

Comment: If you plan on having hundreds of classes you probably *shouldn't* change signatures. It's not just the *methods* that need changing, all their callers will be broken as well. If you can make `Method()` generic (`Method<T>(T foo)`) you won't have to change the type at all.

Comment: change to what, for example? the type of the argument, the name of the argument, the number and order of arguments?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2017 (no ReSharper), it depends on what you mean by "change". You can remove and reorder by highlighting the method name and then selecting `Edit`->`Refactor`->`Remove Parameters` or `Edit`->`Refactor`->`Reorder Parameters`. But, you can't change the existing parameter's type and/or name (that I know of) without something like ReSharper.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/change-method-signature